# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): formProps.date.getTime is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, date

How can I change hour and minute values to an existing Date variable?
**formProps.date**: existing Date type variable generated from a date picker that I want to use year value only.
**formProps.hour**: The hour value that user input separately.
**formProps.minute**: The minute value that user input separately.
Those three values are to be combined into a new Date variable '**dateWithTime**', but it throws an error during copying the date values.

It this a wrong way to copy a Date variable? or is there any better way to make it?

```
const dateWithTime = new Date(formProps.date.getTime());
dateWithTime.setHours(formProps.hour, formProps.minute);
```

[image]

==== edit ====
the log of 
console.log(formProps.date.toLocaleString());
console.log(typeof(formProps.date));
[image]

Comment: It looks like `formProps.date.getTime()` does not have valid value. Can you log out what is value of `dateWithTime`?

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I added the logs. Is it wrong value in formProps.date ?? `dateWithTime` is just a new value.

Comment: Try logging inside `handleRecruitRegister` function. `console.log(dateWithTime)`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma I tried it right below the `const dateWithTime` line, the log cannot be printed out because line 37 is throwing error and other codes below cannot be reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your code above doesn't work but the below code worked for me. Could u try to use:

```
const dateWithTime = new Date(formProps.date.toLocaleString());
```

(I know it is not an comprehensive answer but I couldn't add a comment due to my reputation :/ )

Comment: It worked like magic. thanks !!